# How to update the angular2 firebase database?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have candidates_list table in firebase database. It contains different parameters like name ,city,skill etc. These all parameters I have submitted through one form.
After submitting the form the page is redirect to next page where we want submit his resume. I don't know how to update the candidates_list with resume name and path.

My .html file is below

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">

          <h2>Complete your Profile</h2>
          <h5 style="color:royalblue;">Add your updated Resume to get notified by Recruiters</h5>
          <form>
            <label>Resume</label>
          <input id="file" name="file" type="file" #fileinput ><br>

          <button (click)="upload(fileinput)" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>




          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My .ts page is

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { FirebseService } from "app/firebse.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-candidate-reg-complete',
  templateUrl: './candidate-reg-complete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./candidate-reg-complete.component.css']
})
export class CandidateRegCompleteComponent implements OnInit {
item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private firebaseService:FirebseService) { 
    this.item = db.object('candidates_list');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  upload(documents){
    debugger;
  //  let file=user.files[0];
  //   console.log(file);
  //  console.log(file.name);
  let storageRef=firebase.storage().ref();

    for(let selectedFile of[(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('file')).files[0]]){

     let path='/resumes/'+selectedFile.name;
      let iRef=storageRef.child(path);
      iRef.put(selectedFile).then((snapshot)=>{

       documents.resume=selectedFile.name;
       documents.path=path;
        var Userid=localStorage.getItem('user');
        console.log(documents);
        this.db.object('/candidates_list/'+Userid).update(documents);
      localStorage.setItem('resume',documents.path);

      })
 }

}
}


var Userid=localStorage.getItem('user');
```

Here I mean to take the UID of the user which has set into local storage while logging in.
How to solve this problem. Any solution? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Upload the resume file to firebase storage refer this article [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files)
 If the file is uploaded successfully ,the callback will return a snapshot object , you will get the uploaded file details there. 
  And then you can make a request to update the firebase database with these file details from the snapshot.

Comment: can you please show how to write the update code in this problem,It is uploading the file storage.but i want to store the name and path in the database,but it doesnt work.how to solve this?please help me anyone?

Comment: you can use the update method of the database reference to update a specific keys.please refer this article : [firebase update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)